# Error when writing dask dataframe to mssql via turbodc

Tags: python, dask, turbodbc

I have a dask dataframe which has 220 partitions and 7 columns. I have imported this file from a bcp file as and completed some wrangling in dask. I then want to write this whole file to mssql using turboodbc. I connect to the DB as follows:

```
mydb = 'TEST'

from turbodbc import connect, make_options

connection = connect(driver="ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                     server="TEST SERVER",
                     port="1433",
                     database=mydb,
                     uid="sa",
                     pwd="5pITfir3")
```

I then use the function i found from a medium article to write to a test table in the DB:

def turbo_write(mydb, df, table):
"""Use turbodbc to insert data into sql."""
start = time.time()
# preparing columns
columns = '('
columns += ', '.join(df.columns)
columns += ')'

```
# preparing value place holders
val_place_holder = ['?' for col in df.columns]
sql_val = '('
sql_val += ', '.join(val_place_holder)
sql_val += ')'

# writing sql query for turbodbc
sql = f"""
INSERT INTO {mydb}.dbo.{table} {columns}
VALUES {sql_val}
"""
print(sql)
print(sql_val)
# writing array of values for turbodbc
values_df = [df[col].values for col in df.columns]
print(values_df)

# cleans the previous head insert
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(f"delete from {mydb}.dbo.{table}")
    connection.commit()

# inserts data, for real
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    #try:
    cursor.executemanycolumns(sql, values_df)
    connection.commit()
   # except Exception:
       # connection.rollback()
       # print('something went wrong')

stop = time.time() - start
return print(f'finished in {stop} seconds')
```

This works when I upload a small amount of rows as follows:

```
turbo_write(mydb, df_train.head(1000), table)
```

When i try to do a larger number of rows it fails:

```
turbo_write(mydb, df_train.head(10000), table)
```

I get the error:

> RuntimeError: Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type (compile in
> debug mode for details)

How do i write the whole dask dataframe to mssql without any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to convert to a maskedarray by changing:

```
 # writing array of values for turbodbc
    values_df = [df[col].values for col in df.columns]
```

to

```
values_df = [np.ma.MaskedArray(df[col].values, pd.isnull(df[col].values)) for col in df.columns]
```

I can then write all the data using:

```
for i in range(df_train.npartitions):
    partition = df_train.get_partition(i)
    turbo_write(mydb, partition, table)
    i += 1
```

This still takes a long time to write in comparison to saving the file and writing to the DB using BCP. If anyone has any more efficient suggestions I would love to see them.

Comment: This should write all data in one go? What is the remaining issue?

Comment: It writes all the data selected in the head() only. I have resolved this now and updating the solution.